# python method works outside of Class, but not within Class

Tags: python, class

I am new to python and trying understand and use classes. I haves simple zipcode Class that takes a zip code as a string and makes an object. However, calling any of the method always returns zip code not found. If I run any of the methods outside the class block, it works fine. Any thoughts or ideas is appreciated. Btw, I am using the pyzipcode library for this little project.

```
from pyzipcode import ZipCodeDatabase

class zipCodeProcessor(object):

    def __init__(self, zipcode):
        self.zipcode = zipcode

    #method to extract the Timezone from a given zip code
    def zipToTimezone(zip):
        zipCodeDB = ZipCodeDatabase()
        zipTimezoneQuery = zipCodeDB[zip]
        return zipTimezoneQuery.timezone

    #method to extract the city from a given zip code using pyzipcode
    def zipToCity(zipcode):
        zipCodeDB = ZipCodeDatabase()
        zipCityQuery = zipCodeDB[zipcode]
        return zipCityQuery.city

    #method to extract the state from a given zip code using pyzipcode
    def zipToState(zip):
        zipCodeDB = ZipCodeDatabase()
        zipStateQuery = zipCodeDB[zip]
        return zipStateQuery.state

zipObject = zipCodeProcessor('10005')
zipObject.zipToState()
```

Comment: Did you forget to add  a `self` in the object methods  ?
https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html this might help
specifically class and instance variables. The link is for 2.7.9

Comment: I suggest you look at a basic tutorial on how to use classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's no surprise that code that works fine as a standalone function doesn't work as part of a class. Python isn't magic. You need to revise your methods to not expect the ZIP code as the argument. You've stored `zipcode` as an attribute on your instance when initializing it, so you should be using `self.zipcode` in your methods (and accepting `self` as an argument, of course).

For example:

```
def zipToState(self):
    zipCodeDB = ZipCodeDatabase()
    zipStateQuery = zipCodeDB[self.zipcode]
    return zipStateQuery.state
```

As an optimization, you should also look into not instantiating a new `ZipCodeDatabase` object for each method call. You might instead create a single instance (or an instance per `zipCodeProcessor` instance) depending on how heavyweight it is (not familiar with that particular module, sorry).

Answer (score 0):

Missing "self" as the first argument:

eg., def zipToState(self, zip):
...

Answer (score 0):

zipcode is class-local variable, so you should declare you methods like this :

```
def zipToState(self):
    zipCodeDB = ZipCodeDatabase()
    zipStateQuery = zipCodeDB[self.zipcode]
    return zipStateQuery.state
```